# No puedo quitar height en div con mediaquery con orientación landspace

Tags: html5, css3, responsive

```
<div id="shufle">

</div>
```

css

```
@media screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape){
    #shufle
   {

     height: 200px;

   } 
   #shufle p 
   {
    margin-top: -50px;
   } 

}
 }

@media (min-width: 992px) {

  #shufle  {
    height: 1050px;
  }


  #shufle p 
  {
    margin-top: 350px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }


}
```

No consigo quitarle height a shufle en orientacion landscape. si puedo cambiar el color de fondo del div pero la altura no puedo modificarla. ¿como puedo ver que otros estilos me están impidiendo modificar la altura?.

Estoy usando Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que está mal cerrada la media-query de 768px, tiene un corchete de más. Prueba ahora con esto:

css

```
 @media screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape){
    #shufle  {  height: 200px;  } 
    #shufle p {  margin-top: -50px; } 
  }

  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    #shufle  { height: 1050px;}
    #shufle p {  margin-top: 350px; font-size: 30px; text-align: center;  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ver con las herramientas de desarrollador de Chrome por ejemplo las clases css que afectan a tu elemento.

Para cambiarlo bastaría con decirle que esa propiedad css manda sobre las demás, esto se hace con `!important`:

```
@media screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape){
    #shufle {
     height: 200px !important;    
   } 
   ...
}
```

Comment: ni usando !important puedo hacerlo. cuando giro la tablet en horizontal el #shufle no coge los estilos

Comment: Pueba a poner sólo esta media query @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px){#shufle {height: 200px !important;} }, sin ninguna otra, para descartar la posibilidad de que no esté entrando en la primera que tienes declarada y ver si cambia el alto, asi descartas si es el elemento o la media query el problema